# How to read new line symbols with Java SAXParser

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax

I receive XML files via network and I don't have any DTDs assigned to them. I need to read new line symbols (\n) from Text nodes. My code:

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setValidating(true);
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
parser.parse(file, handler);
```

I extended DefaultHandler and overrode these methods:

```
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException
 public void ignorableWhitespace(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException
```

But characters() method doesn't receive new line symbols and ignorableWhitespace() is never called.

How to configure my parser to receive \n symbols also? 
I need all the information from Text nodes including new lines. Is it possible with standard SAXParser? Is there any alternative library with the same interface?

Comment: Can you share your extended handler code?
share handler variable init code.

Comment: It is pretty simple:

Comment: It is pretty simple:

 `handler = new SaxHandler();`

`public class SaxYmlHandler extends DefaultHandler {
.............
}`

I've only overriden endElement, ignorableWhitespace, characters and startElement there.

Comment: correct init of handler variable. you are not putting your class.
handler = new SaxYmlHandler();